# Confused about use of dirname and rtrim - PHP code (OpenCart)

Tags: php, opencart, dirname

I am trying to understand some piece of code.

```
define('HTTP_OPENCART', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 'install'), '/.\\'). '/');
```

What I am unable to understand is:

A) [rtrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php): According to PHP manual, rtrim function should only receive two parameters. I think the first one is `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`
Which is the second one? This `/.\\` ??

Is it possible to have that in the second parameter taking into account that the manual says `With .. you can specify a range of characters`  Please note it talks about two full stops (not one, as it is in the code).

And what about the last part of the code? `'/'`

B) [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php): According to PHP manual, this function should only receive one parameter which is (in my opinion), in this case, ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']). What is the meaning of `,'install'` over there?

I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested rtrims - result of nested rtrim is first parameter to external rtrim. Final string is composed of 'http://', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], two nested rtrims and '/'

Answer (score 0):

The `rtrim`s are nested. They are performing a dual function.

The first part of this function: `rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 'install')` is stripping the word "install" off of the right side of the folder name in which this particular script resides. IE. If `opencart.php` resides in a folder called "opencart-install", this folder name is being reduced to "opencart-".

The second part of the function: `rtrim("opencart-", '/.\\')` is using regex (Regular Expressions) to attempt to strip off any ".\" characters from the target string "opencart-".

So, once you've figured out what your dirname is, you should be able to work through the logic from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This particular script resides in /var/www/opencart/upload/install and it is called index.php. After applying `rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 'install'), '/.\\'`  what is the result? I think the answer is /var/www/opencart/upload/  Could you confirm this, please? Thanks in advance. As the other answer says, the final string is composed of / at the end  (please, correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: The final definition of the constant **HTTP_OPENCART** would be: `http://localhost/var/www/opencart/upload/`

Comment: Second argument of rtrim is just character set. Not regex, not word.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good code. Let's format them.

```
define(
    'HTTP_OPENCART',
    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .     // 5. result of concatination would be http://domain.some.com/dir/
        rtrim(                              // 4. removes /, ., \ characters from right and return /dir
            rtrim(                          // 3. removes i,n,s,t,a,l characters from right and return /dir/
                dirname(                    // 2. should return /dir/install
                    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] // 1. returns something like /dir/install/index.php
                ),
            'install'
            ),
            '/.\\') .
    '/');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems this regex `'/.\\'` tries to strip off .\ but unfortunately can't find it here: `/dir/`  What do you think? This comment is about step 3 and step 4.

Comment: `'/.\\'` -- it's not regex. It's just 3 chars: '/', '.', '\'

Comment: Thanks for writing the code in a different way. How do those 3 chars strip off the last `/` of `/dir/`? Thank you

Comment: I am confused. Regarding rtrim, php manual says `With .. you can specify a range of characters`  The problem is that there is not two full points in `'/.\\'`

Comment: With two dots (..) but there is only one dot (.)

Comment: In my opinion, that's the problem: the code of the software has only one dot which means, in my opinion, that `'/.\\'` is not the second parameter of the first rtrim.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41148/discussion-between-sectus-and-pablofiumara)